# What is the format of a unique Google Hangout with app id?

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm building my first Google Hangout app and can access it successfully using the URL:
`https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_/?gid=APP_ID`
or `https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/?gid=APP_ID`

What is the proper format of a URL that contains a unique hangout id that could be shared across users so they end up in the same hangout **and** using the app?

The following URL loads a unique hangout, but discards the app:
`https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/UNIQUE_HANGOUT_ID?gid=APP_ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested `https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/UNIQUE_HANGOUT_ID?gid=APP_ID` this evening, and it worked correctly - placing the person in the same hangout and running the correct app.

Is the app in question public? If not, this may be the cause of the problem.

As an aside, the `https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/` is now deprecated, since it was related to the old Hangout Development Sandbox which is no longer in use.

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem: my app isn't public yet. Good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the name of the parameter to add start'data to that url?

Comment: Nevermind, found the answer in https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.getStartData look at getStartData function where it says "This is the data passed in by the gd URL parameter"